# Existence of an open normal subgroup of a neighborhood of 1 in a compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected topological group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ a compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected topological group. Then every neighborhood of 1 contains an open normal subgroup of finite index in $G$. I need this lemma to prove that every compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected topological group is a profinite group. I am trying but I can not prove it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma 3.9 in [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/250C/notes/profinite.pdf).

If and when I have more time, I can copy the proof or you can DIY.

Comment: I was using the book "Introduction to Profinite Groups and Galois Cohomology" by Ribes, and the argument is similarly, but he picked up another symmetric neighborhood.